# How do I map a JSON object with nested arrays into a typescript model?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

Suppose I had an api that returns the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "status": {
      "code": "SUCCESS",
      "message": "owner found",
      "count": "1"
    },
    "owners": [
      {
        "ownerId": "12345",
        "name": "Example Person",
        "cars": [
          {
            "make": "Toyota"
            "year": "2004"
            "model": "Camry"
          } 
        ]
      }
    ] 
  }
}
```

I want to map this json structure into these typescript models:

```
export class ApiResponse{
  constructor(
    public status: Status,
    public owners: Owner[]
  ) {}
}
export class Status {
  constructor(
    public code: string,
    public message: string,
    public count: number
  ) {}
}
export class Owner{
  constructor(
  public ownerId: number,
  public name: string,
  public cars: Car[]
  ) {}
}
export class Car{
  constructor(
    public make: string;
    public year: string;
    public model: string;
  )
}
```

From my understanding of angular 7, you can use pipe and map from rxjs to achieve this:

```
this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((data: any[]) => data.map((item: any) => new ApiResponse(
      new Status(
        item.status.code,
        item.status.message,
        item.status.count),
...
```

Using this I am able to map a JSON object, but I am unsure how to approach mapping arrays and nested arrays.

How should I approach mapping a JSON with nested arrays?

Comment: If your model definitions are really nothing but property lists, they are functionally equivalent to interfaces.  As such, there's no need to instantiate new objects, because nothing is gained -- TS enforces type checking for interfaces as well as classes. Just return the `Observable` to the component for rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your classes will not implement any new functionality you should use interfaces just to enforce strong types, otherwise is just boilerplate.
As you started you can derive your 4 interfaces like so and benefit from the Typescript safety check:

```
export interface ApiResponse{
    status: Status,
    owners: Owner[]
}
export interface Status {
    code: string,
    message: string,
    count: number
}
export interface Owner{
    ownerId: number,
    name: string,
    cars: Car[]
}
export interface Car{
    make: string;
    year: string;
    model: string;
}
```

Your method that calls that API can be written like this:

```
getStatusAndOwners(url): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```

When you will consume the data (in the subscribe block most probably) you will benefit from "IntelliSense" and strong typing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response, this works as needed. Something to note is that I needed to cast the get function to fit the return value: `this.http.get<ApiResponse>(url);`

Comment: True, because we expect an `Observable<ApiResponse>`. Well done!